# JaxWsProxyFactoryBean for Mule CXF transport?

Tags: spring, cxf, mule

I am new to mule. Are there any way to call CXF based web services using JaxWsProxyFactoryBean? It will be nice to reuse Java interface instead of wsdl files.

With CXF we can simply reuse our java interface as spring bean for web services client without wsdl2java code generation.

```
<bean id="{Bean Id}" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
<property name="serviceClass" value="{java interface}"/>
<property name="address" value="{Address}"/>
</bean>
```

Instead of generating client artifacts we can simply use the above bean definition for web service consumer.

Thanks in advance
Maska

Comment: That's a hopelessly vague question. You'll need to be an awfully lot more specific than just listing a bunch of technologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is: "what is the way to invoke a remote web service without generating client classes in Mule 2.2.x", the answer is: "[use a generic WSDL endpoint](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE2USER/WSDL+Connectors#WSDLConnectors-GenericWSDLEndpoints)".